# How to send ctrl+z in C

Tags: c, character

I'm working with Arduino.

I want to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> after a string in C. I tried truncating `^Z` but that didn't work. So how to do that ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart for further reference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> = 26 = `'\032'` = `'\x1A'`.  Either of the backslash escape sequences can be written in a string literal (but be careful with the hex escape as if it is followed by a digit or A-F or a-f, that will also be counted as part of the hex escape, which is not what you want).

However, if you are simulating terminal input on a Windows machine (so you want the character to be treated as an EOF indication), you need to think again.  That isn't how it works.

It may or may not do what you want with Arduino, either; in part, it depends on what you think it is going to do.  It also depends on whether the input string will be treated as if it came from a terminal.

Comment: can you tell say how you went about translating that. For example a table of conversion? I'm most interested in CTRL + a

Comment: The ASCII characters 'A' to 'Z' have character codes 65-90, and the `@` symbol has code 64.  The control characters control-A through control-Z map to the character code for the (upper-case) letter minus 64, so control-A is code 1, while control-Z is 26.  The character code 0, aka the null byte, is also encoded as control-@ (or ^@), so typing shift-control-2 on many keyboards (including, specifically, the one I'm typing on) will send a null byte to the terminal driver. You occasionally see the characters with codes 91-95 used for control characters 27-31 — so ^[ (aka ESC), ^\, ^], ^^ and ^_.

Comment: thanks; I sort of understood. So control-A is code 1 but how do you then work it all the way to how you had with cntrol-Z which was '\x1A'

Comment: The `'\x1A'` notation uses a hex representation for the character.  In hex, `1A` means `1 * 16 + 10` which is 26 decimal (and `'\032'` or `'\32'` in octal = `3 * 8 + 2`).

Answer (score 6):

I hacked this up as I needed similar

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define CTRL(x) (#x[0]-'a'+1)
int main (void)
{
    printf("hello");
    printf("%c", CTRL(n));
    printf("%c", CTRL(z));
}
```

hope it helps 8)

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "truncating" you actually meant appending.

In ASCII, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> is code point 26 so you can simply append that as a character, something like:

```
#define CTRL_Z 26
char buffer[100];
sprintf (buffer, "This is my message%c", CTRL_Z);
```

The `sprintf` method is only *one* of the ways of doing this but they all basically depend on you putting a single byte at the end with the value 26.

Comment: such as simply using the escape sequence \xFF where FF are two hex digits that are for the code. so: "This is my message\x1A"

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:
whatever you are trying to write append `\032` at the end
For example:

```c
strcpy(InputCommand,"hi\032");
GetSerialData(InputCommand,......); //this is my own function which uses serialPuts()
```