# How do i put a newline command without pressing enter in C?

Tags: c, buffer, newline

I'm on Linux, using C99 and my problem is: I programmed a multi-option based on integers. For every iteration past the first, inputting more integers than needed for the array would trigger other menu options as they remain into the buffer.
I wanted to avoid the `fflush(stdin)` function as I read it causes undefined behaviour, so i tried with `while ((select = getchar()) != '\n')`, but in the first iteration, I need to press Enter for the menu to appear in the first place. Can I send a Newline to the buffer to avoid the problem?
Also, I declared `select` as an `int`

Here is the part of the code that causes the problem:

```
for(;;) {
    while ((select = getchar()) != '\n') { }
    printf("\n\nWhat operation?\n1. Define array\n2. Delete element\n3. Add element\n4. Order array\n5. Randomize array\n6. Print array\n0. Exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &select);
    switch(select) {...}
```

Comment: What do you get if you always print the return value of scanf() ?

Comment: On which operating system?

Comment: @Yunnosch Random memory location (4195338) at the start of the loop, 10 after hitting enter, 10 after the printf("What operation?...");
110 from the second iteration.

Comment: Without more details and some [MCVE] we can only guess what you are asking

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Linux!

Comment: That should go into your question. Never comment your own question, but do **edit your question** to improve it

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks, will do! Sorry, I'm totally new to this website

Comment: When you are done reading up on scanf() you will probably realise that the return value cannot be 10 or 110. But never mind, you already got help. For the future however, if you have a problem involving scanf(), always make sure that you report the return value in the problematic case. You will always be asked about it otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pure standard C, what you want is probably impossible (and certainly ill-defined) and unclear. The C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) does not know about terminals or keyboard (so about the <kbd>enter</kbd> key), but only about [standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43844150/841108) answer to a question close to yours.

In practice, if you are on some POSIX system (which I guess you are on), the terminal has a [line discipline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_discipline) managed by the kernel. However, the standard input might not be a terminal (with [redirections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) or [pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix))) and you could check if it is one by using [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) as `isatty(STDIN_FILENO)` ...

I recommend using some library like [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) or [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) when that is the case.

BTW, your use of `select` name is confusing (since [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) was an old system call, today superseded by [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)).

If you are restricted to pure C standard functions, read *carefully* the documentation of [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), and use its return count. You certainly cannot (portably) put a newline (or any other characater) into some input stream like  `stdin`. But read carefully about [ungetc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ungetc).

I recommend to compile with all warnings and debug info (so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` [with GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html)) and to learn to [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your program.

Answer (score 2):

Use fgets to read a line. Parse the line with sscanf. Parsing for an integer and a trailing non-whitespace character will allow detection of any input that follows the integer.
EDIT to improve due to @chux's comment

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void) {
    char buffer[100] = "";
    char extra = '\0';
    int scanned = 0;
    int choice = 0;

    do {
        printf("\n\nWhat operation?\n1. Define array\n2. Delete element\n3. Add element\n4. Order array\n5. Randomize array\n6. Print array\n0. Exit\n");
        if ( fgets ( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
            if ( 1 == ( scanned = sscanf ( buffer, "%d %c", &choice, &extra))) {// the space will consume whitespace and %c a non-whitespace character
                printf ( "choice %d\n", choice);
                if ( 0 > choice || choice > 6) {
                    scanned = 0;
                }
            }
            if ( 1 != scanned) {
                printf ( "\t\tenter a number 0 to 6\n");
            }
        }
        else {
            fprintf ( stderr, "problem fgets\n");
            return 0;
        }
    } while ( 1 != scanned);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: `"%d%1s"` would be sufficient to detect trailing non-white-space.